# Cannot login through ssh from same lan

Tags: lan, centos-7, sshd

I have two CentOS7 servers on the same VLAN. I can ping the destination from the source server but cannot ssh to the destination :

```bash
source # ping -c5 destination
PING 172.16.15.101 (172.16.15.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.15.101: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.301 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.15.101: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.331 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.15.101: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.359 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.15.101: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.359 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.15.101: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.367 ms

--- 172.16.15.101 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 received, 0% packet loss, time 3999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.301/0.343/0.367/0.029 ms

source # traceroute destination
traceroute to 172.16.15.101 (172.16.15.101), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  destination (172.16.15.101)  0.260 ms  0.332 ms  0.317 ms

source # : < /dev/tcp/destination/ssh
source # echo $?
0
source # time timeout 30s ssh destination

real    0m30.002s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.006s
source # echo $?
124
```

Although there is no iptables rules on the destination server :

```bash
destination # iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

destination # systemctl status sshd
● sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2023-01-11 16:21:02 CET; 28min ago
     Docs: man:sshd(8)
           man:sshd_config(5)
 Main PID: 2581 (sshd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/sshd.service
           └─2581 /usr/sbin/sshd -D

Jan 11 16:21:02 destination systemd[1]: Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
Jan 11 16:21:02 destination sshd[2581]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Jan 11 16:21:02 destination sshd[2581]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Jan 11 16:21:02 destination systemd[1]: Started OpenSSH server daemon.
```

EDIT0 : `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` only contain comments :

```bash
destination # egrep -v "^(#|$)" /etc/hosts.allow /etc/hosts.deny
destination #
```

```bash
source # ssh -vv destination
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "pan-scal-wit01" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to pan-scal-wit01 [172.16.15.101] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to pan-scal-wit01:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
```

Comment: check `/etc/hosts.allow` and `/etc/hosts.deny` for sshd entries, and/or try adding your client to allow. If you do `ssh -vv`, what is the reason it fails to connect?

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Please take a look at my EDIT0.

Comment: Does this help? [SSH fails (…) and hangs here "expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY" (…)](https://askubuntu.com/q/1229456/693277).

Comment: Similar replies here: https://serverfault.com/a/848953/411612 looks like you can get around the bug by specifying part of the key exchange or altering the MTU size (only if it's weird on your network, like due to vpn)

Comment: @Cpt.Whale You're right it is a MTU missmatch between the two servers, I'll try to align them both to 9000 bytes because we use jumbo frames. Thanks.

Comment: @Cpt.Whale It was indeed a MTU mismatch. After "aligning" the MTU, the ssh worked fine. Can you please convert your comment to an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on it hanging on `expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY`, I found similar replies here: https://serverfault.com/questions/210408/cannot-ssh-debug1-expecting-ssh2-msg-kex-dh-gex-reply/848953#848953

It looks like you may be able to get around buggy SSH client/server by specifying part of the key exchange:

```
ssh -o MACs=hmac-sha2-256 <HOST>
```

or altering the MTU size (only if it's weird on your network, like due to vpn)

```
ip li set mtu 1400 dev wlan0
```

Comment: Thanks. I aligned the MTUs on both servers (using jumbo frames here), and it solved the problem.